# JNI printf to log4j

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, printf, stdout

I call some C code via JNI from JAVA.

In my C, I do multiple printf that I want to log with log4j.

```
    printf("Could not find HID device\n");
    fflush(stdout);
```

They show up fine in the Eclipse console, with log4j I redirect the stdout to my logger :

```
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStreamLogger(log, Priority.DEBUG), true));
```

When I call "System.out.println", it's written to my log file.

But the JNI printfs don't. 
Aren't they in the stdout ?
How can I put them in my logfile ?

Comment: `System.setOut` changes where `System.out.println` is directed, from `stdout` to your custom stream. It does not actually change `stdout`.

Comment: Is there a way to capture all the stdout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is to use *dup* and *dup2* inside your JNI core. This way, you can associate your stdout with the file that is used by Log4J.

```
int newStdout(const char *filename, fpos_t *pos)
{
  fflush(stdout);
  fgetpos(stdout, pos);
  int fd = dup(fileno(stdout));
  freopen(filename, "w", stdout);
  return fd;
}

void revertStdout(int fd, fpos_t *pos)
{
  fflush(stdout);
  dup2(fd, fileno(stdout));
  close(fd);
  clearerr(stdout);
  fsetpos(stdout, pos);
}
```

Then, in your code you can use it like this:

```
fpos_t pos;
char filelocation[256] = "some_place";
int fd = newStdout(filelocation, &pos);
//
//... do some stuff here ...
//... things that put data into stdout ...
//
revertStdout(fd, &pos);
```

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but still, might be a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

They in `stdout`.

Problem is that `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStreamLogger(log, Priority.DEBUG), true));` just instruct to use custom print stream instead of `stdout`.

You problem do not have simple solution.

Simplest that I can imagine is to change you `c` code to use `Java` logger.

I suggest you to live with it or setup `c` logging and have two log files. It will be much easier.

Comment: System.setOut reassigns the standard output stream to my custom printstream. If the stdout is redirected to the new PrintStream, and the printfs are in the stdout, why aren't they redirected ? Does it redirect only explicit calls ?

Comment: Not from OS point of view. `stdout` is file handler with value `1` AFAIR. After that call nothing happens with it.

Comment: How does Eclipse console manage to print them ? Of course I can create a log file from C but I would like to understand

Comment: You logger actually prints to OS `stdout` and Eclipse read those output.