# How Can I Create JNI Interface for Traceroute C File

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm working on Android application which is a network utility. One of the utility is traceroute implementation using activity and xml file. Implementing traceroute in java is kind of a pain, so I looked to JNI and C code. There's a utility that include many linux tools called busybox. It is open source and has traceroute. here's the code on github https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mirror/busybox/master/networking/traceroute.c
My question is how can I implement JNI interface in java for this file. The file one compiled acts as a command line tool which you run and pass the parameter of the host you want to traceroute. Does that mean I have to implement only the main method in JNI. Also, this file doesn't have the JNI type methods so I wont be able to interface directly with it. Do I need to create another C file that calls traceroute main method using JNI C code. Any input appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You want to call this method: `common_traceroute_main(int op, char **argv)`

You have to create shared library using the code from github. Take a look here

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-001/

Once you have your library, you have to prepare parameters inside Java and pass them to JNI code, where you need to unpack them and convert to what is expected by `common_traceroute_main`.

For example. You can pass array of `String` and convert them to `char **argv`.

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-009/

Then, all you have to do is to call `common_traceroute_main` from your JNI wrapper.

**Solution draft**

You will need Java code, for example, something like this

```
public class TraceCaller {
  public static native callTraceRoute(int op, String[] args);
}
```

once you compile it using `javac -h headers TraceCaller` you will find C header file.

Inside this header file, you will have to extract values from array of strings. Take a look here (https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo038/java/recipeNo038/PassHashMap.java) to get the feeling of how to retrieve `String` objects from array inside `JNI` code and turn them into `char*`.

Once you have (inside `JNI`) both: `int op` and array of `char *` you can simply call routine: `common_traceroute_main`.

Once it's finished, you have to pass data back (either as return value or via object passed to JNI).

Take a look here on sample that shows how to pass `String` back to Java:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo010

And, you are done :)

Comment: I thought you write your java wrapper first then generate header file and finally write your c native code. The traceroute file takes a main method and print string to screen. my c native file interfacing with traceroute can't be that complicated. first time doing jni

Comment: yeah I know what you explain, but I'm stock in writing the native c code that will interface with traceroute as I can't access traceroute directly from java as is not written in native. I need some native method that can pass args from java to traceroute. and then pass return string back to java

Comment: the problem with my traceroute c file is that it is void. it prints everything printf to stdout. how can I get that output and use it in java?

Comment: You can redirect stdout to file using dup method. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083058/jni-printf-to-log4j/45091701#45091701 - Well, it won't be a piece of cake, to link all that stuff together. But, you are entering low level territory :(

Comment: I'm testing the app with a simple printf but nothing prints to console... if I change it to return statement I get string back, but can't see printf working... where does printf in c prints stdout?